# New films will refresh when the submit button is pressed after the range slider has been moved (Laravel)

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I am building a web application that will show a variety of films on a site. As part of this project I have some range sliders that can be moved depending on the mood you are feeling. If someone is to move the slider and press submit, I am wanting a fresh new list of films to displayed.

This is where I am having issues, I am able to display a set amount of films on the page but can't figure out a way to refresh the films once I click the submit button after moving the sliders.

Code Below

> Upload (view)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/app.css" type="text/css">
<meta name = "viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://www.w3schools.com.  /lib/w3.css">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Moodslider</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Sky logo + Sky cinema logo -->
<div class="box">
<td style="text-align:center;color:black;font-size:50px;">
     <img src="/images/sky.png"  title="Sky" alt="Sky" width="auto" height="125" />
   </td>
   <td style="text-align: right;position: relative; color:black;font-size:50px;">
     <img src="/images/sky_cinema.png"  title="sky_cinema" alt="Sky" width="auto" height="125" />
   </td>
  </div>

   <!-- This is the navigation bar for the homepage and the upload content page. -->
  <div>
  <ul class="w3-navbar w3-black">
  <li><a href="/projects/upload">Moodslider Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/projects/create">Upload Content</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>

 <div class="w3-row-padding">
  <div class="w3-panel">
    <h1 style="text-align:center;color:black;font-size:50px;">Select a movie based on your mood</h1>
  </div>

 <form action="/projects/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ @csrf_field() }}
  <div class="col-md-12">

<div class="w3-row-padding">
<div class="w3-col m3 w3-center">
<label for="Agitated"><h3>Agitated</h3></label><br><br>
<label for="Happy"><h3>Happy</h3></label><br><br>
<label for="Tired"><h3>Tired</h3></label><br><br>
<label for="Scared"><h3>Scared</h3></label><br><br>
</div>

<div class="w3-col m6 w3-center">
<br>
<form action="/projects/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ @csrf_field() }}
<div></div>
<input type="range" name="mood1" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="1";/><br><br>
<input type=submit value=Submit />

 <br>
 <br>
 <input type="range" name="mood2" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="1" class="slider" id="myRange"><br><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 <br>
 <br>
 <input type="range" name="mood3" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="1"  class="slider" id="myRange"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<br>
 <br>
<input type="range" name="mood4" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="1" class="slider" id="myRange"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<br>
<br>
</div>
</form>
<div class="w3-col m3 w3-center">
 <label for="Calm"><h3>Calm</h3></label><br><br>
 <label for="Sad"><h3>Sad</h3></label><br><br>
 <label for="WideAwake"><h3>Wide Awake</h3></label><br><br>
 <label for="Fearless"><h3>Fearless</h3></label><br><br>
</div>
 </div>

</form>

 <!-- display the films images -->
<form action="/projects/upload">

   <div class="w3-row">
 <div type="text" name="lname" class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><img src=<?$xml=simplexml_load_file("images/database.xml");
 echo '../'.$xml->programme[1]->image?> ; alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:150px"></div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><img src=<?$xml=simplexml_load_file("images/database.xml");
 echo '../'.$xml->programme[2]->image?> alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:150px"></div>
 <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><img src=<?$xml=simplexml_load_file("images/database.xml");
 echo '../'.$xml->programme[4]->image?> alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:150px"></div>
 <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><img src=<?$xml=simplexml_load_file("images/database.xml");
 echo '../'.$xml->programme[6]->image?> alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:150px"></div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><img src=<?$xml=simplexml_load_file("images/database.xml");
 echo '../'.$xml->programme[5]->image?> alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:150px"></div><br>

   <!-- display the film name and description -->
   <? $xml=simplexml_load_file("images/database.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");?>
  <div class="w3-row"></div>
  <div class="w3-row">
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><h3><?echo $xml->programme[1]->name?></h3></div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><h3><?echo $xml->programme[2]->name?></h3></div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><h3><?echo $xml->programme[4]->name?></h3></div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><h3><?echo $xml->programme[6]->name?></h3></div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><h3><?echo $xml->programme[5]->name?></h3></div>

  <div class="w3-row">
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><p><?echo $xml->programme[1]->description?></p></div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><p><?echo $xml->programme[2]->description?></p></div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><p><?echo $xml->programme[4]->description?></p></div>
  <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><p><?echo $xml->programme[6]->description?></p></div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-container" style="width:20%"><p><?echo   $xml->programme[5]->description?></p></div>
</div>
</form> 
<!--
<form action="/projects/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">Select image to upload:
{{ @csrf_field() }}
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
-->

</body>
</html>
```

> ProjectsController (controller)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Facade as XmlParser;

interface OutputType
{
public function generate();
}

//project class has been imported
use App\Project;

class ProjectsController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    //because the class has been imported we can reference it like this rather than '\App\Project::all();'
    $projects = Project::all();



//passing the JSON to the view

    return view ('projects.index', ['projects'=> $projects]); //can also use 'compact('projects') instead of the ['projects'=> $projects]
}



//new method called create

public function create()
{

    return view ('projects.create');

}

  //new method called store


 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->xml= new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-15');
    }

    public function createParent($type)
    {
        $this->parentElement = $this->xml->createElement($type);
        return $this;
    }

    public function addElement($element, $type)
    {
         $this->elementGroup = $this->xml->createElement($type, $element);
         return $this;
    }

    public function groupParentAndElements()
    {
        $this->parentElement->appendChild($this->elementGroup);
        return $this;
    }

    public function generate()
    {
        $this->xml->appendChild($this->parentElement);
        print $xml->saveXML('database.php'); //here I am saving and printing but you can change to suit your needs. It is at this point it is ready to generate the XML
    } 

 public function store()
  {

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $xmlType = new XMLType();
    $xmlType->createParent('programme')
            ->addElement('name', $_POST['name'])
            ->addElement('description', $_POST['description'])
            ->addElement('mood', $_POST['mood'])
            ->groupParentAndElements()
            ->createParent('others')
            ->addElement('example', 'Form submitted succesfully')     //echos response
            ->groupParentAndElements();

    //whenever you wish to output
    $xmlType->generate('database.php');
    }


return view('projects.upload');
}


//changed this from upload to show
public function upload()
{


return view('projects.upload');
}

//changed this from upload to show
public function show()
{


return view ('projects.upload', compact('user'));
}

public function slider()
{


return view ('projects.upload', compact('user'));
}


}
```

> Database(XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<programmeList>
<programme id="1">
<name>School of Rock</name>
<image>images/schoolofrock.jpg</image>
<description>After being kicked out of a rock band, Dewey Finn becomes a substitute teacher </description>
<mood>Agitated</mood>
</programme>
<programme id="2">
<name>Pitch Perfect 2</name>
<image>images/pitchperfect2.jpg</image>
<description>After a humiliating command performance at The Kennedy Center, the Barden Bellas enter an international competition that no American group has ever won in order to regain their status and right to perform.         </description>
<mood>Fearless</mood>
</programme>
<programme id="3">
<name>Big</name>
<image>images/big.jpg</image>
<description>When a pre-teen boy wishes to be big at a magic wish machine, he wakes up the next morning and finds himself in an adult body.</description>
<mood>Tired</mood>
</programme>
</programmeList>
```

Comment: You should try to dynamically display your data - this will take up less lines of code and be more future-proof (i.e. if you add more programmes to your programme list). You can do this by decoding the json array and using a foreach loop foreach($programmes as $programme) etc....

Answer (score 0):

You need to POST the request data (from the form which the user submits) and display the films based on that. You will need some logic to determine which mood in the database you are searching for, and set that to the variable $mood which you will search for in your projects table.

In your controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

   // Need logic that checks if there is anything in the request
   // If there is nothing in the request, then show all films

   // Repeat this for every input slider you have
   $mood1 = $request->input('mood1'); // This will return the value of the slider

   // You will need some logic which will calculate which mood to search
   // your database for, i.e. if $mood1 < 3 && $mood2 > 1 etc.
   $mood = /** LOGIC FOR YOUR MOOD **/ ;

   $projects = Project::where('mood', $mood);

return view ('projects.index', ['projects'=> $projects]);
}
```

In your form you will need

```
<form action="/projects/upload" method="POST">
// And importantly, you will need to protect against CSRF when POSTing
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

And you will also need to create a 'POST' route.

Hope this helped!